# Alternative for Struts result type="dispatcher" in struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm using Struts 2.3.16.
I've a requirement like I can't use "redirectAction" as the request parameters gets lost. Also I can't use result type="dispatcher" as the struts version is not allowing me to do.
Can anybody please suggest me an alternative to result type = "dispatcher".

```
<action name="merchantsignupsubmit class="com.idmission.idp.action.MerchantSignupAction"
        method="execute">
         <result name="success" type="forwardAction">${merchantsignupconfirm}</result> 
        <result name="merchanterror">jsp/merchant/signup/merchant_signup.jsp</result>
        <result name="employeeerror">jsp/merchant/signup/merchant_signup.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">jsp/merchant/signup/merchant_signup.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Earlier I was using the above code. If the "execute()" return "success" I want to go the other action "merchantsignupconfirm".
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Put your stuff in session, then retrieve it from the second action, mapped with "redirectAction".

Comment: How exactly S2 is not allowing you to use `dispatcher` result? :)

Comment: I don't want to use "redirectaction". @Andrea Ligios

Comment: I guess the latest version of struts have restricted the use of that. @Aleksandr M

Comment: No restriction on that. But a dispatcher will map a page, generally JSP, not another Action. Then if you need to return another Action, you need to use redirect**A**ction result.

Comment: I'm aware of redirectAction, but I've faced some issues with that. And yes you are correct about the jsp and action. And that's what I'm searching for an alternative so that I can redirect to action also.

Comment: The problems you faced with redirectAction are the problems *everyone* faced with redirectAction: since it is a new request, previous request parameters are lost. But then, you need to find a way to preserve the parameters, instead of another way to redirect to an action. The way is that, the problem is that, try to solve the problem, instead of modifying its nature... one of the solutions is to put the data in session in action1, then retrieve it and clean it up in Action2. They're three total rows of code.

Comment: That's not at all my problem. Earlier I was using redirectAction and I also managed to preserve the data using interceptors.The problems which I'm facing are something different and I just wanted make sure that I won't face any furthermore issues so I need to change the whole implementation.And that is why only I'm asking for an alternative.